# How to get Shadow on UIView as from Top side Only ? [ Objective-c ]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I  want shadow on `UIView` From Top side only as shown in image below.

I am trying this code to  apply shadow , but shadow is applied on right side of view but i want it from top side.

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0);
CGRect shadowPath = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.dealMainContentView.bounds, contentInsets);
self.dealMainContentView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowPath].CGPath;
self.dealMainContentView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.dealMainContentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,0.0f);
self.dealMainContentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4f;
self.dealMainContentView.layer.masksToBounds=NO;
```

This how it should look like

[image]

Comment: self.dealMainContentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,-5.0f);

Comment: @GeneCode This won't give exactly the expected result. Shadow will be as wide as view layer itself.

Comment: @vaibhav that is now working .. still getting shadow at right side

Comment: @Dhiru use signed value at y position `CGSizeMake(0.0, -5.0);` this will place the shadow image to bottom side as i mentioned in my ans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this with own , i was able to get the desired shadow  by modifying the frame before making Path  .

just the hack :)

Instead of passing view.frame in this method i modified the frame
`UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(viewFrame, contentInsets);`  and got shadow from top side .

this is the code below

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10, -10, 0, 0);

    CGRect viewFrame=self.dealMainContentView.frame;

    viewFrame.origin.x += 5; // 5 distance from left
    viewFrame.origin.y -= 15;
    viewFrame.size.width -= 1o;  // 5 distance from Right
    viewFrame.size.height -= 20;

   CGRect shadowPathExcludingTop = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(viewFrame, contentInsets);

   self.dealMainContentView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowPathExcludingTop].CGPath;
    self.dealMainContentView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.dealMainContentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0,0.0f);
    self.dealMainContentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3f;
    self.dealMainContentView.layer.masksToBounds=NO;
```